# Anchor a Stripe subscription after next natural billing date

Tags: stripe-payments

I am working on a Stripe integration for a user with some very specific rules for a yearly subscription plan on Stripe:

1. If the user starts the subscription between 2022-01-01 and 2022-09-30, they shall be charged the full amount immediately and next on 2023-01-01 - From then on, the charge will be yearly
2. If the user starts the subscription between 2022-10-01 and 2022-12-31, they shall be charged the full amount immediately and once again on 2024-01-01 - From then on, the charge will be yearly

My immediate guess is that case #1 should be possible with a combination of backdates, anchors, no-prorate and/or trial periods, although I haven't tested the specifics yet.

How can I implement case #2, when the anchor for the next charge is in more than 12 months? To my knowledge, Stripe disallows anchor dates that are further into the future than the next natural billing date (which is 12 months for a yearly subscription). It is also not possible to have a trial_end later than the anchor date.

I am using Laravel Cashier/PHP on the backend, but I doubt it comes out-of-the-box, so I am merely looking for the API options for creating the subscription in any language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve your first scenario by setting `backdate_start_date` to 2022-01-01 and `billing_cycle_anchor` to 2023-01-01.

As you note, Stripe does not allow billing periods of longer than 12 months but there are some workarounds for it.

One option is to create a subscription with a year+ long trial but with a one time charge of the subscription's yearly fee. To do this when creating the subscription you would backdate the start date to 2022-01-01, set a `trial_end` and `billing_cycle_anchor` of 2024-01-01, and use the `add_invoice_items`[1] parameter to create a one time charge with the same amount as your yearly fee.

Alternatively you can create a subscription schedule[2] with a first phase that ends 2023-01-01, a trial phase that lasts a year, and then a phase with your year-long price.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-add_invoice_items

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules

Comment: Wow, that just worked out-of-the-box exactly as you dictated (went with the add_invoice_items option). It's quite the complicated process, but it's good to hear there's a workaround available. Thank you very much!

Comment: This answer helped me recently.  When working with Stripe subscriptions, I highly recommend using a PaymentIntent with `setup_future_usage` set to `off_session` to perform an initial charge (and also prepare the PaymentMethod for the subscription), then use the `trial_end` option to set the true anchor of the subscription when creating the subscription.  This approach solves a number of very difficult problems related to creating Stripe subscriptions that are not really documented anywhere.